# 2D plot does not looks like a 2D slice of 3D plot

Tags: plotting

As you can see, the maximum of my function is further, than the "T" is 1.1 at "V" is 2

"T" - temperature, "V" - volume

But when I plot 2D plot with "V"=2 and "T" from 0.9 up to 1.3, the maximum is located at "T" smaller, than 1

Why?
[image: screenshot]

Code for function

`msclf[V_, T_] := msclnon /. {v -> V, t -> T}`

The msclnon.mx file you can get on [link](https://wdfiles.ru/587dc5) or [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/H80WFKX2)

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code, the chance to get helpful answers  grows significantly!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann added

Comment: Using *pastebin*  function definition I cannot reproduce your plots.

Comment: The 1D plot of `msclf` at `V=2`does not look at all like the `V=2` slice through the 2D plot.  I suggest you run your code again with a new notebook.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I rerunned all calculation, but output plots are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

You have a precision problem. Your `msclnon` is way too complicated to be evaluated with machine precision. Use either [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) or [`SetPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) on the function and specify a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) in the plot to use arbitrary-precision.

```
msclnon = (-3.4555696794583572*
     E^(900./
         t^2 + (0.9999999999999997 + 0.9999999999999999*v + 61.*v^2 + 1.*v^3)/
         v^4)*(t^(-1))^146.*
     v^17)/(E^(900./
          t^2 + (0.9999999999999997 + 0.9999999999999999*v + 61.*v^2 + 
            1.*v^3)/v^4)*
      v^14*(8.765182207002524*^6*(t^(-1))^146.375 - 
        4.9276687267765775*^7*(t^(-1))^146.75 + \
(-4.660091636885849*^7*(t^(-1))^146.5 + 
           1.358160830023902*^8*(t^(-1))^146.875)*
         v + (-2.1704073645558745*^7*(t^(-1))^146.25 + 
           1.155719827100718*^7*(t^(-1))^146.875)*v^2 - 
        1.1734423517504692*^7*(t^(-1))^146.*v^3) + 
     E^(600./t^2 + 
         677.9999999999999/
          t + (0.9999999999999998 + 0.9999999999999998*v + 46.*v^2 + 31.*v^3)/
          v^4)*(t^(-1))^148.*
      v^10*(-2.3380917465924074*^-165 + 4.676183493184815*^-165*v - 
        1.6366642226146853*^-165*v^2 - 6.234911324246418*^-166*v^3 - 
        3.1174556621232096*^-167*v^4) + 
     E^(625./t^2 + 
         687.5/t + (0.9999999999999997 + 1.*v + 36.*v^2 + 51.*v^3)/
          v^4)*(t^(-1))^149.*
      v^11*(-2.6224141865524763*^-184 + 5.244828373104953*^-184*v - 
        2.2552762004351297*^-184*v^2 - 3.1468970238629714*^-185*v^3 - 
        6.293794047725946*^-187*v^4) + 
     E^(575./t^2 + 
         754./
          t + (0.9999999999999996 + 0.9999999999999999*v + 41.*v^2 + 41.*v^3)/
          v^4)*
      v^12*(-9.032491675804817*^-188*(t^(-1))^146. + 
        9.603194194414136*^-188*(t^(-1))^147. + \
(1.8064983351609633*^-187*(t^(-1))^146. - 
           1.9206388388828272*^-187*(t^(-1))^147.)*
         v + (-7.903430216329216*^-188*(t^(-1))^146. + 
           8.40279492011237*^-188*(t^(-1))^147.)*
         v^2 + (-9.032491675804821*^-189*(t^(-1))^146. + 
           9.603194194414135*^-189*(t^(-1))^147.)*
         v^3 + (-1.1290614594756024*^-190*(t^(-1))^146. + 
           1.2003992743017665*^-190*(t^(-1))^147.)*v^4) + 
     E^(900./t^2 + (0.9999999999999997 + 0.9999999999999999*v + 61.*v^2)/v^4)*
      v^7*(-7456.837734301234*(t^(-1))^146.75 - 
        35723.37299101869*(t^(-1))^148.5 + (12629.368592526356*(t^(-1))^146. \
+ 134223.07921742223*(t^(-1))^146.75 + 643020.7138383364*(t^(-1))^148.5 + 
           161134.8607225736*(t^(-1))^148.75)*
         v + (-202069.89748042173*(t^(-1))^146. - 
           86300.69160657328*(t^(-1))^146.5 - 
           536892.3168696889*(t^(-1))^146.75 - 
           2.5720828553533456*^6*(t^(-1))^148.5 - 
           2.5781577715611784*^6*(t^(-1))^148.75 - 
           197229.02861715946*(t^(-1))^149.)*
         v^2 + (707244.6411814761*(t^(-1))^146. + 
           1.2082096824920261*^6*(t^(-1))^146.5 + 
           9.023552200464122*^6*(t^(-1))^148.75 + 
           2.7612064006402325*^6*(t^(-1))^149.)*
         v^3 + (-3.624629047476079*^6*(t^(-1))^146.5 - 
           2.0195059533157113*^6*(t^(-1))^147. - 
           8.2836192019207*^6*(t^(-1))^149.)*
         v^4 + (2.0195059533157114*^7*(t^(-1))^147. - 
           4.941959931996473*^6*(t^(-1))^147.25 + 
           190053.34103404023*(t^(-1))^149.5)*
         v^5 + (-4.039011906631422*^7*(t^(-1))^147. + 
           3.953567945597179*^7*(t^(-1))^147.25 - 
           1.5204267282723214*^6*(t^(-1))^149.5)*
         v^6 + (-6.628276809318786*^6*(t^(-1))^146.5 + 
           1.8976910415048514*^7*(t^(-1))^146.75 - 
           5.9303519183957696*^7*(t^(-1))^147.25 + 
           5.648893183337791*^6*(t^(-1))^148. + 
           2.280640092408481*^6*(t^(-1))^149.5)*
         v^7 + (2.651310723727514*^7*(t^(-1))^146.5 - 
           7.590764166019407*^7*(t^(-1))^146.75 - 
           2.259557273335115*^7*(t^(-1))^148.)*
         v^8 + (-1.3256553618637562*^7*(t^(-1))^146.5 + 
           3.795382083009702*^7*(t^(-1))^146.75 + 
           1.1297786366675586*^7*(t^(-1))^148.)*v^9) + 
     E^(900./t^2 + (0.9999999999999997 + 61.*v^2 + 1.*v^3)/v^4)*
      v^3*(270209.93340586894*(t^(-1))^158. + \
(317158.63766474964*(t^(-1))^157. - 1.801399556039127*^6*(t^(-1))^158. - 
           3.895163290490197*^6*(t^(-1))^161.)*v^3 + 
        4.879349840998319*^6*(t^(-1))^162.*
         v^4 + (-1.4800736424354985*^6*(t^(-1))^157. + 
           2.1616794672469525*^6*(t^(-1))^158. + 
           1.8177428688954256*^7*(t^(-1))^161.)*v^6 - 
        1.951739936399328*^7*(t^(-1))^162.*
         v^7 + (1.057195458882499*^6*(t^(-1))^157. - 
           1.298387763496733*^7*(t^(-1))^161.)*v^9 + 
        1.084299964666294*^7*(t^(-1))^162.*v^10) + 
     E^(900./t^2 + (0.9999999999999996 + 1.*v + 60.*v^2 + 1.*v^3)/v^4)*
      v^5*(2590.913859383711*(t^(-1))^152. - 
        24613.681664145253*(t^(-1))^152.*v^2 - 
        191892.0803486235*(t^(-1))^149.*
         v^3 + (996024.2700448286*(t^(-1))^149. + 
           46636.4494689068*(t^(-1))^152.)*
         v^4 + (1.2472985222660534*^6*(t^(-1))^149. - 
           1.8289005666359053*^6*(t^(-1))^152.)*
         v^5 + (-5.478133485246559*^6*(t^(-1))^149. + 
           3.394416171383404*^6*(t^(-1))^152.)*
         v^6 + (-1.4391906026146768*^6*(t^(-1))^149. + 
           2.0453679216516896*^6*(t^(-1))^150. + 
           8.230052549861575*^6*(t^(-1))^152.)*
         v^7 + (4.980121350224145*^6*(t^(-1))^149. - 
           1.1880456599841917*^7*(t^(-1))^152.)*
         v^8 + (-5.113419804129224*^6*(t^(-1))^150. - 
           5.486701699907716*^6*(t^(-1))^152.)*v^9 + 
        5.091624257075105*^6*(t^(-1))^152.*v^10 + 
        1.0226839608258456*^6*(t^(-1))^150.*v^11) + 
     E^(900./t^2 + (0.9999999999999999 + 61.*v + 1.*v^2)/
          v^3)*(-49722.50594911337*(t^(-1))^162. - 
        251065.829485316*(t^(-1))^150.*
         v^3 + (828944.7802124461*(t^(-1))^153. + 
           285904.4092074021*(t^(-1))^162.)*v^4 - 
        1.6839653717821308*^6*(t^(-1))^158.*v^6 + 
        1.0670297753125934*^6*(t^(-1))^150.*
         v^7 + (-3.108542925796674*^6*(t^(-1))^153. - 
           279689.095963763*(t^(-1))^162.)*v^8 + 
        4.630904772400863*^6*(t^(-1))^158.*v^10 - 
        659047.8023989551*(t^(-1))^150.*v^11 + 
        1.554271462898338*^6*(t^(-1))^153.*v^12 - 
        1.2629740288365986*^6*(t^(-1))^158.*v^14));
```

Your rationalized function

```
msclf[V_, T_] = Rationalize[msclnon, 0] /. {v -> V, t -> T};
```

Plotting,

```
Quiet[
 Plot3D[msclf[V, T],
  {V, 1/10, 46/10}, {T, 9/10, 15/10},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20,
  AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  ClippingStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
You've solved a lot of my previous problems